# printing all variables created by a dynamic variable in range of {i}

Tags: python

I'm trying to print all the variables I've created up to a point specified by a counter,  but I get an error saying
`KeyError :variable1`,   in my head it should work but it doesn't. What I'm trying to do is to make a type if input history and to call that input history when I type 00 in the length catagory. Example is in code below

```
COUNTER1 = 1
while True:
    L = float(input("Length    :"))   
    count = 0    
    if L==00:
        globals()[f"variable{COUNTER1}"] = f"{L}"
        while count < COUNTER1:
            print(globals()[f"variable{COUNTER1}"])
            #where it should loop and print all variables created
            for i in range(1, COUNTER1):
                print(globals()[f"variable{i}"])            
            count = count + 1            
print(L)
COUNTER1 = COUNTER1 + 1
```

Comment: Oh dear. Don't use a hack like setting variables via `globals()` when you really need a dict or a list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, im new to python , started a week ago, wont a list or dict make it limeted to what i entered in the code?

Comment: Well, in any case your program doesn't make much sense. Since incrementing `COUNTER1` is outside the loop and you only ever set a variable if `L == 0`, you'll only ever have `variable1`.

Comment: `globals()[f"variable{COUNTER1}"]` is using `globals` as a dict, so just make your own dict and use that instead.  FYI I don't get a KeyError if I run this code - is it inside a function in some bigger piece of code?  In that case your vars aren't part of `globals` :)  Anyway, just use your own dict

Answer (score 0):

So, as said, you don't want to use `globals()`; if you want some sort of command history thing, put your entries in a list, á la

```
entries = []

while True:
    d = input("Enter some text (or a blank entry to stop): ")
    if d == "":
        break
    entries.append(d)

for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
    print(f"{i}. {entry}")
```

This prints e.g.

```
Enter some text (or a blank entry to stop): foo
Enter some text (or a blank entry to stop): bar
Enter some text (or a blank entry to stop): quux
Enter some text (or a blank entry to stop): 

0. foo
1. bar
2. quux
```

Or, if you actually do want a dict (that associates keys with values),

```
entries = {}

while True:
    key = input("Enter a key (or a blank entry to stop): ")
    if key == "":
        break
    value = input("Enter a value: ")
    entries[key] = value

for key, value in entries.items():
    print(f"* {key}: {value}")
```

e.g.

```
Enter a key (or a blank entry to stop): color
Enter a value: purple
Enter a key (or a blank entry to stop): smell
Enter a value: roses
Enter a key (or a blank entry to stop): 

* color: purple
* smell: roses
```

Comment: Thats precisely what im looking for,  Thank you so much!